# Fetch and use response to change state in React

Tags: reactjs, formik

I would like to change the state of a component based on the response of a PUT request using [react-refetch](https://github.com/heroku/react-refetch).

Especially when the response of the PUT is unsuccessful, as is the case with for example a 500 response.

The following example is an example in a form. When a user submits the form it should then fire off a PUT.

If the PUT response is fulfilled, it should reset the form. Otherwise nothing should happen, and the user should be able to retry.

**./MyForm.jsx**

```js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { PromiseState } from "react-refetch";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import ResetOnSuccess from "./ResetOnSuccess";

const MyForm = ({ settingsPut, settingsPutResponse }) => {
  const submitForm = (values, formik) => {
    settingsPut(true);

    // Here it should pick up the settingsPutResponse,
    // and then do the following ONLY if it's successful:
    //
    // formik.resetForm({ values });
    // window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        noValidate
        initialValues={{ name: "", password: "" }}
        onSubmit={submitForm}
      >
        {({ dirty }) => (
          <Form>
            <ResetOnSuccess settingsPutResponse={settingsPutResponse} />
            <Field type="text" name="name" />
            <ErrorMessage name="name" component="div" />
            <Field type="password" name="password" />
            <ErrorMessage name="password" component="div" />
            <button type="submit" disabled={dirty !== null ? !dirty : false}>
              Submit
            </button>
            {settingsPutResponse && settingsPutResponse.rejected && (
              <p style={{ color: "red" }}>Please try again</p>
            )}
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

MyForm.propTypes = {
  settingsPut: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  settingsPutResponse: PropTypes.instanceOf(PromiseState)
};

MyForm.defaultProps = {
userSettingsPutResponse: null
};

export default MyForm;
```

I might have a solution by creating a component:

**./ResetOnSuccess.jsx**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useFormikContext } from "formik";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { PromiseState } from "react-refetch";

const ResetOnSuccess = ({ settingsPutResponse }) => {
  const { values, resetForm } = useFormikContext();
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (settingsPutResponse && settingsPutResponse.fulfilled) {
      setSuccess(true);
    }
  }, [settingsPutResponse]);

  // only if settingsPutResponse is fulfilled will it reset the form
  if (success) {
    resetForm({ values });
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    setSuccess(false);
  }

  return null;
};

ResetOnSuccess.propTypes = { settingsPutResponse: PropTypes.instanceOf(PromiseState) };
ResetOnSuccess.defaultProps = { settingsPutResponse: null };

export default ResetOnSuccess;
```

And then in **./MyForm.jsx** add the reset component:

```js
<Formik
  noValidate
  initialValues={{ name: "", password: "" }}
  onSubmit={submitForm}
>
  {({ dirty }) => (
    <Form>
      <ResetOnSuccess settingsPutResponse={settingsPutResponse} />
      <Field type="text" name="name" />
      <ErrorMessage name="name" component="div" />
      <ResetOnSuccess settingsPutResponse={settingsPutResponse} />
      // etc...
```

But since it's a component that returns a 'null'. This feels a bit like an anti-pattern.

Is there a better way?

I've created an codesandbox example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-johnson-dberw

Comment: Use the component lifecycle method getDerivedStateFromProps. It is called after new props are received by a component.                                                                                                   Sample:-static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
   if(nextProps.someValue!==prevState.someValue){
     return { someState: nextProps.someValue};
  }
  else return null;
}

Comment: The getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle method is only possible with a class component. In a functional component this would be handled in the useEffect right?

Comment: Yes @Remi, I missed that.